# linux echo extra slash

Tags: linux, echo

I am creating a script which will go into into a particular column and row in a CSV file and use this data as part of a file subdirectory.  So, I have a directory = $d and a sub-directory = $s

My scripts works really well, but this is not the important part.  When I try to output some information in the script like..

```
echo "file $d/$s was unable to be replicated"
```

I get this output on the screen...

```
file /home/jsigel//filename was unable to be replicated
```

What do I need to do to get rid of this extra slash?  I've tried a thousand things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Normally this extra output slash should not harm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra slash is harmless, but you can remove it from your output if you like with

```
echo "file ${d%/}/$s was unable to be replicated"
```

If `$d` does have a trailing slash, it will be removed and an explicit `/` output in its place. If `$d` does not have a trailing slash, no change is made, and again the explicit `/` will be output.

Comment: I don't think it's a trailing slash, I think it's a leading slash (given his example of $d/$s creating /home/jsigel//filename ($d is /home/jsigel & $s is /filename)

Comment: A trailing slash in a directory is far more common than a leading slash in a subdirectory (or a file name). But that, too, could be removed with `${s#/}`.

Comment: Agreed, I was just commenting to the possibility

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains the `'/'` so it's not necessary in your output specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Super simple:

```
echo "file $d$s was unable to be replicated"
```

*just as Kevin said a few seconds faster than me...*